# FreeTTS Portability Issue

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts

I'm writing an application that makes use of Java's speech API and FreeTTS. The application works fine when I run it from the Netbeans IDE, but when I try to run it from a jar file on my local machine or on other machines, I get the following error:

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/speech/freetts/VoiceManager"

Is there any way for me to include the FreeTTS files in my jar file so it can run anywhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not include the FreeTTS jar file itself with your distribution?

Comment: RTFM. The documentation on their site tells you all you need to know. http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html#how_app

Comment: I've read the manual, and it actually says very little about this. It says something about including the jar file in a class path, but doesn't say how this is accomplished or even if it would be necessary to do this on every machine that runs a program that makes use of freetts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem and i found this page:
 http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/misc/freetts-line-unavailable-classcastexception-kevinvoicedirectory-error-opening-zipfile.texy

I did the easy way, which was to add the `freetts` installation to my dist folder, change the manifest of my jar on where to find the `jsapi.jar`,  `freetts.jar` etc. and it is worked. I am just distributing freetts inside my folder.

The hard way is on the link above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does look like distributing the jars in the dist folder is the best solution.